# Use wget and an IP to download huge file?

Tags: shell, wget

I have a server with IP 1.2.3.4 but that IP is not connected to any domain. I created a huge tar.gz file on the shell on that server using putty. The file resides in **/var/www** on that server. Now I want to get that file on another server using wget.

I tried some commands but nothing worked. How would I get that file on my other server?

Thanks!

Comment: Presuming the web server is working (why you put it in `/var/www`) you would use `wget http://1.2.3.4:/path/from/DOCROOT/to/huge.tar.gz`. If no web server, then `rsync 1.2.3.4:/path/to/huge.tar.gz` `wget` only supports HTTP HTTPS and FTP.

Comment: Looks promising, I am getting 403 Forbidden using wget.

Comment: Well you found the server. I suspect your problem is `/var/www`. It should go beneath the DOCROOT which is generally `/var/www/html` or `/var/www/htdocs`.

Comment: Same problem when using /var/www/html :/

Comment: No, no, your `huge.tar.gz` has to go beneath the DOCROOT within your webserver directory. Generally `/var/www` is the SERVERROOT and you do not have external access to files in that directory. So `huge.tar.gz` must go where you serve web pages from. (where your `index.html` lives -- or below there in the dir structure). Then `wget` can access it via `http://`

Comment: This is what I get using wget. /var/www/html is the path where the app resides, too. But it is not accessible from the outside anymore. Its just on the server.

Comment: --2018-04-19 08:14:19--  http://1.2.3.4:/var/www/html/file.tar.gz
`Connecting to 82.165.138.142:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2018-04-19 08:14:19 ERROR 403: Forbidden.`

Comment: Can you access any of the files on that server via `http://`? Did the web server croak? `wget` accesses files just like you do from your browser. So if you can't see the file in a browser, `wget` isn't going to find it. Do you have a way to confirm which directory on the server is able to provide web pages to the outside world? (403 means the server is running -- you are just not allowed to access where you are trying to get to) What Linux distro is the server running? You can check what the default path should be with a quick web search.

Comment: Its just not working, neither with wget nor scp nor rsync. Ill just download and upload via FTP. THANKS anyway!

Comment: Also, check the file permission on `huge.tar.gz`. They must be *world readable*, e.g. at least `0644` meaning `-rw-r--r--` so the file can be read by the outside world.

Comment: Yeah, I set them to 777 just to be sure, didnt help

Comment: I'm out of ammo then. It's really just a case of being able to reach the file with a browser -- if you can, you can `wget` it, if you can't, well -- go to plan B. I can get to the shop page at `https://www.kleiderbuegel-shop.mawa.de/` which is where your IP resolves, but have no way to tell where the document root is from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a working web server like apache or lighttpd and document root is /var/www.

```
$ wget http://1.2.3.4/huge.tar.gz
```

If wget is not a must, you can just simply use scp between the two server.

Comment: $ scp user@1.2.3.4:/var/www/huge.tar.gz .

Comment: I am sorry, dont get it :)